# Bundle vector-icon with the app for offline access

Tags: android, react-native, assets, expo, vector-icons

I used 2 icons with Ionicons from @expo/vector-icons for a React Native app.

Is there a way to bundle the 2 icons to the app such that the user would not require internet connection to get the icons rendered?

Answer (score 3):

For ionicicons or other icons you can prefer react-native-vector-icons module. For further refernce about module follow link.
[Vector icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

These icons are bundled inside your app and user does not need internet access to rendered icons.

Comment: Not sure about ejected apps, but for Expo internet access is required to access the icons https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/assets.html

Comment: Ok, you just have to build once your app after implementing the module, then user does need  internet access for rendering them.

Comment: Have u used Expo? This is not the case for unejected Expo app.

Comment: Sorry my bad, in this case you can once you fetch those icons, you can save them at local system (mobile), then use can see them without internet, but in this case user need to connect to internet at least once to load icons.